# Integrated graphics shows shimmering display

Tags: 14.04, graphics, intel-graphics

Dear Linux enthusiast,

When I boot Ubuntu, and the current GPU is set to the integrated graphics (ie an Intel HD 4600), the display shimmers sideways like old CRTs used to sometimes. Individual lines randomly shimmer back and forward horizontally about 2 or 3 pixels. It's still readable, but tiring on the eyes. And definitely wrong.

If I change the current GPU to the discrete GPU (ie an NVIDIA GTX 980M 8GB vram), and reboot in Linux, the display looks fine.

Details of my system:
It's a new laptop, an MSI GT72 2QE. The integrated graphics is Intel HD 4600, the discrete GPU is a GTX 980M 8GB vram.

I have installed Windows 7 Pro (64bit) on the fist mSATA, and Ubuntu Desktop 64bit V14.04.1 LTS on the second mSATA. These mSATA drives are now (obviously) not in raid configuration. I have taken the boot settings back from UEFI to MBR. I've installed Grub2 and the system dual boots fine.

There is a button on the laptop that (under Windows) can explicitly switch between the integrated GPU and the discrete GPU, and this requires a reboot.

Windows 7 shows no problems I can see with either GPU (apart from the usual Windows problems :-)

The only problem I have seen with Ubuntu is the shimmering display on the integrated GPU as described at the top. I would like to be able to use Linux with the integrated GPU because I will rarely need powerful graphics in Linux.

One other point is that the integrated graphics was selected when I did the Ubuntu install. The shimmering was evident right through the install and afterwards when it booted from the mSATA drive.

Thanks very much,

Peter Bruderlin

Answer (score 0):

must be something wrong with the card or the install. i have the GT72 with the 970m and it works fine under Ubuntu using the Intel graphics. im running 14.10 though. maybe try the Intel Graphics Installer for Linux.